# Python requests - [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for

Tags: python, nginx, requests, ssl, python-3.11

Кажется проблема появилась недавно, возможно из-за каких-то обновлений, а может быть все проще и я не вижу глупую ошибку.
Имеется сервер с поднятым nginx в докере, с self-signed сертификатом. Необходимо внутри программы на Python устанавливать соединение с этим сервером, используя именно этот сертификат. (Отключать проверку сертификата нельзя).
Для этого делаю

```
r = requests.get("https://212.80.219.194:5443", verify='path/to/cert.pem')
```

В указанном файле лежит сертификат, который я достал руками из браузера, перейдя по адресу моего сервера. И подчеркну, что и браузер, и curl отлично принимают этот сертификат. А Python делает так:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='212.80.219.194', port=5443): Max retries exceeded with url: /check_license (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '212.80.219.194'. (_ssl.c:992)")))
```

IP адрес, для которого сертификат якобы не подходит, на самом деле и прописан в этом сертификате.
Уже перекопал интернет по этому поводу, не могу судить насколько досконально. Но пробовал поставить в сертификат *subjectAltName* IP сервера, что тоже не помогло.

*P.S. IP сервера в коде реальный, если я чего-то не учел и нужно самому посмотреть этот сертификат прямо с сервера - смотрите. Или если нужно самому проверить ошибку в питоне.*
Python 3.11 последний, с последними версиями библиотек. Надеюсь на вашу помощь, ибо сам уже не понимаю что происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, все оказалось проще:

1. Теперь у сертификатов действительно обязательно должен быть subjectAltName - в него необходимо указывать адрес сервера
2. Если используете напрямую IP, то при создании сертификата он должен быть прописан в *.ext* файле как IP.

Моя ошибка состояла в том, что адрес был прописан как DNS запись, и я этого не заметил.